# Excel - VBA - Imagem no Corpo do E-mail - GMAIL

Tags: excel-vba, envio-de-email

Excel VBA - EMAIL usando GMAIL

Bom dia pessoal!

Preciso enviar uma imagem no corpo do e-mail, no momento estou usando o código abaixo, como faço para incluir uma imagem ao final do texto?

Tentei incluir o código abaixo mas não deu certo... Envia o e-mail normalmente mas sem a imagem.

```
.HTMLBody = Email_Body & "<html><body><img src=""G:\SETOR DE CADASTRO\WELLINGTON\SIGN.jpg""></body></html>"
```

---

```
 Private Sub btnEmail_Click()
 Dim myMail As CDO.Message
 Set myMail = New CDO.Message
 Dim Login_EmailAddress, Login_EmailPassword, SMTPServer As String
 Dim ServerPort, x, linha As Integer
 Dim To_Email, CC_Email, BCC_Email, Email_Subject, Email_Body, Attachment_Path As String
 Dim FileExtn As String

 FileExtn = ".PDF"

 SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
 ServerPort = 465
 Login_EmailAddress = Sheet1.Range("O2").Value
 Login_EmailPassword = Sheet1.Range("O3").Value
 With myMail.Configuration.Fields
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = ServerPort
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Login_EmailAddress
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Login_EmailPassword
.Update
End With

Range("A1").Select
linha = Range("A999").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To linha
To_Email = Cells(x, 1).Value
CC_Email = Cells(x, 2).Value
'BCC_Email = Sheet1.Range("L4").Value
Attachment_Path = Cells(x, 7).Value
Email_Subject = Cells(x, 8).Value
Email_Body = Cells(x, 9).Value

If Sheet1.Range("G2").Value <> "" Then
Sheet1.Calculate 'to refresh sheet
Attachment_Path = VBA.UCase(Sheet1.Range("G2").Value)

If VBA.InStr(Attachment_Path, FileExtn) > 0 Then Attachment_Path = VBA.Replace(Attachment_Path, FileExtn, "")

End If

With myMail
.From = Login_EmailAddress
.Subject = Email_Subject
.To = To_Email
.CC = CC_Email
.BCC = BCC_Email
.HTMLBody = Email_Body & "<html><body><img src=""G:\SETOR DE CADASTRO\WELLINGTON\SIGN.jpg""></body></html>"
If Attachment_Path <> "" Then .AddAttachment Attachment_Path & FileExtn
End With

On Error Resume Next
myMail.Send

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
Else
Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

Next x

Set myMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Pronto! Vi em uma outra pergunta daqui algo similar e obtive uma resposta, porém... Gerou outra dúvida. A solução é no lugar do caminho da imagem, inserir um link de uma imagem da web. Dessa forma dá certo, porém o que eu quero enviar não posso publicar assim na web, gostaria que fosse tirado do meu drive compartilhado, tentei e não consegui, mesmo alterando as configurações de privacidade para qualquer usuário da WEB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um meio possível porem não tão prático, é publicar previamente a imagem em um repositório externo como Google ou AWS e apontar para a imagem no HTML.

```
.HTMLBody = Email_Body &  <html> <body><img src="https://www.freelogoservices.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/logo-color_image.jpg"></body></html>
```

Normalmente quando precisei fazer isso, subia a imagem no Google Fotos, localizar o link direto independente de autenticação e usava para anexar minha assinatura em um envio massivo. Não consegui encontrar outro meio de anexar a imagem no corpo do e-mail já que conectava diretamente no servidor via SMTP.

Comment: Foi assim que consegui fazer, obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score -1):

Tens de incluir a imagem e escondê-la. A posição `0` vai adicioná-la e escondê-la, o `1` é a constante do Outlook `olByValue`.

```
.Attachments.Add FILENAME, 1, 0
```

Assim que adicionares a imagem tens de utilizar a `src` como `src="cid:FILENAME.jpg"`.

Experimenta adicionar esta linha:

```
.Attachments.Add "G:\SETOR DE CADASTRO\WELLINGTON\SIGN.jpg", 1, 0
```

E no html:

```
.HTMLBody = Email_Body & "<html><body><img src='cid:SIGN.jpg'></body></html>"
```

Comment: Quem votou contra podia pelo menos dizer o que está errado

Comment: Bom dia! iamdIm, o código que compartilhei acima é para enviar e-mail pelo GMAIL, sem Outlook. As funções do outlook não funcionam com ela. Estou usando CDO.message. a função .Attachments.Add nem funciona nela. Eu já encontrei vários materiais na internet sobre fazer isso usando outlook e é conforme você informou acima. Mas com GMAIL é diferente, Por desencargo de consciência eu até testei esse seu código, mas da erro e nem roda.